# Which WebGL framework and/or tool to create a certain project

Tags: framework, 3d, web

Searched the internet and found a lot of information about WebGL frameworks and tools but still need help to decide which to learn and use for a certain project.

Project basics:

A quite complex 3d object is loaded in a WebGL viewport. At first sight only the wireframe of the loaded 3D object is visible, the 'triangles' (mesh) in between the wireframe are invisible.
When the visitor navigates over the currently invisible 'triangles', the 'ID' and coordinates of the 'triangle’ (mesh), which the visitor is currently over (hover) with the cursor, are shown.
Mouse 'cursor' is a 'pen' cursor that moves over the 3d surface.
When the visitor clicks on one of the currently invisible 'triangles', this clicked 'triangle' becomes visible.

Question:

Which WebGL framework and/or tool (Threejs (Whitestormjs), Babylonjs, Xeogl, Blend4web, ...) will fit the best to create this project?

When i know which WebGL framework and/or tool to choose, i can start to search a developer to write the basic core of this project.

Thanks for any hints and tips!

Comment: Just curious - how do you know that you need a WebGL framework?

Comment: Because i need interactive 3d content on a webpage.